# Generate Unique id based on month and date MYSQL

Tags: mysql, unique

I am working on a small software for a doctor for his personal use. He wants the Unique id of the patient to be a combination of year, month and number of patient of the month. e.g. for fifth patient in july 2016 id should be 2016-07-05 and when the month changes id should be reset to 1 again. How it can be achieved in mysql db? I can put do it in php code, but i want to do it in the database table and save the lines of code from executing every-time. I searched around but I was unable to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved with few manipulations over `id` in the table.

1. compare only prefix of the id to know what month the last person belonged to e.g for `2016-09-id` compare only `2016-09-` with current date
2. if the month or year is not changed then we find the max id by only comparing the id of person and increment it by one and concatenate with date
3. else we concatenate date with 1

Here is the example query for table `person(id, name)`

```
    insert into person(id, name) 
         select if(max(id) is null, concat(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-'), '1'), 
                   if(max(substr(id, 1, 8)) = date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-'),
                       concat(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-'), 
                       max(substr(id, 9)+1)), 
                   concat(date_format(now(), '%Y-%m-'), 1))) as nextid, 'lastperson' 
         from person;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
CONCAT(YEAR(NOW()),'-',MONTH(NOW()), '-', IFNULL((SELECT MAX(P) FROM person WHERE <...>)+1,1));
```

But that requires you to have a counter somewhere.